# Model not using correct schema

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have the following changes added to the `ApplicationUser` class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim> 
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual int OrganizationId { get; set; }
        public virtual int? ProfilePictureId { get; set; }
        public bool IsBroker { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("OrganizationId")]
        public virtual Organization UserOrganization { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProfilePictureId")]
        public virtual File UserProfilePicture { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that `Organization` and `File` are not in the same schema as the one that IdentityFramework is using `dbo`.

When I try to use that element to get the `Organization` information for that user:

```
ApplicationUser currentUser = (from u in dbIdentity.Users 
                               where u.Id == var1  
                               select u).SingleOrDefault();
string organizationName = currentUser.UserOrganiztion.OrganizationName;
```

I get the following error:
[image: Trying to get dbo.Organizations]

It's trying to get `dbo.Organizations` which doesn't exist and is in another schema.

Is it possible to change which schema is being used? And if so where?

Thank you!

Comment: There are someways to change the schema at runtime: http://forums.asp.net/t/1912127.aspx?How+to+change+the+schema+at+run+time+using+EntityFramework

Comment: override the OnModelCreating method and use

`modelBuilder.Entity<T>().ToTable("Name", "schemaName")`